# Json.NET deserialize one of many objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Json.NET to deserialize the response from a third party restful API (don't have control over this and unfortunately can't use a different one). The API returns either a response object or an error object.

At the moment both my response and error objects inherit from a base object and I deserialize to that and then cast to the type that it is.

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseMessage>(responseContent);

switch (response)
{
    case ResponseMessage responseMessage:
        return responseMessage;
    case ErrorMessage error:
        return error;
}
```

The `ResponseMessage` and `ErrorMessage` are nothing alike, nor contain a field that says which type it is. I just know from the schema. Imagine they're like the following.

```
public class BaseMessage
{
}

public class ResponseMessage : BaseMessage
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorMessage : BaseMessage
{ 
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The only reason that they both inherit from BaseMessage is so that I can deserialize to that type and then cast to the type that it actually should be.

Is there a better way of knowing which object the JSON should deserialize to?

Comment: A good response should have a status of 200 Done.

Comment: @jdweng 200 OK you meant? ;)

Comment: The API is a third party one so I don't have control over that :)

Comment: Well, the other option you could opt for is use another API, but that's normally not a real option

Comment: Have you looked at [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/10263)?

Comment: What is this api? Is it public? Are you sure you read the instructions carefuly? If not. Use brian rogers link.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a standard response that looks as follows:

**For success:**

```
{
 "status": 200,
 "message": "Stored Successfully!",
 "result" : {
     "some_attr": "some value",
  }
}
```

**For Failure:**

```
{
 "status": 302, //or any other standard response code
 "message": "Token missing", //Any other error message
 "result" : {
     // error object or empty result if no need to add details to error.
  }
}
```

So now all you need is to deserialize/serialize to an object that looks like:

```
int status;
string message;
dynamic result;
```

and you get the rest of the scenario.

**Edit:**

For APIs that do not support this kind of format and you have no control over it, you can either pick an attribute in the success object to manually check for it's existence using `JObject`.

Or try deserializing to `success object` else, deserialize to `error object` on exception (this feels a little bit hacky but a third part api that does not provide a standard `HTTP Response` will force you to use such hacks anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to inspect the response first before deserializing to the desired type

```
//...

var response = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

if (response.ContainsKey("ErrorCode")) { //Or what ever the actual key is
    return response.ToObject<ErrorMessage>();
}

if (response.ContainsKey("Status")) { //Or what ever the actual key is
    return response.ToObject<ResponseMessage>();
}

//...
```

The above uses `JObject` to parse the response and inspect the keys to determine what type to parse the response.